# Importing a list from text file to compare to dataframe with isin()

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a dataframe of addresses, including zip codes. I am trying to see if those zip codes are valid by importing a list from a text file of valid zip codes. I can't seem to get the correct datatype either from the list or the dataframe.

My list looks like this in the text file

```
00501, 00544, 00601, 00602, 00603, 00604, 00605, 00606, 00610, 00611, 00612, 00613, 00614, 00616, 00617, 00622, 00623, 00624, 00627, 00631, 00636, 00637, 00638, 00641, 00646, 00647, 00650, 00652, 00653, 00656, 00659, 00660, 00662, 00664, 00667, 00669, 00670, 00674, 00676, 00677, 00678, 00680, 00681, 00682, 00683, 00685, 00687, 00688, 00690, 00692, 00693, 00694, 00698, 00703, 00704, 00705, 00707, 00714, 00715, 00716, 00717, 00718, 00719, 00720, 00721, 00723, 00725, 00726.....
```

And I am importing the list like so...

```
text_file = open("/C:/valid_zipcodes.txt", "r")
zip_codes = text_file.readlines()
```

I'm looking to return a bool with the is in function. This works if I create a very simple list in the code

```
zip_codes2 = [12401,12603]
df['valid_zip'] = df['Zip Code'].isin(zip_codes)
>>valid_zip True

print(df.dtypes)

>>Zip Code int64
```

I've tried to the datatype to object with the following, it changed to object, but couldn't find it's counterpart in the list from the text file. Even when I adjusted the textfile to read '12345','12346'.

```
df['Zip Code'] =  df['Zip Code'].astype(str)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How do you store a zip code like `00723` as an integer. I suspect your issue is that you're missing the leading `0`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to split by ", ". Note also that `readlines` returns a `list`, one element for each line. It appears your input file only consists of one line, so you will need to extract the first element of your list.

Finally, you need to ensure you compare strings with strings or integers with integers. In the below example, I assume the leading `0`s are important and compare strings throughout.

```
from io import StringIO

text_file = StringIO('00501, 00544, 00601, 00602, 00603, 00604')

## create set of zip codes
zip_codes = set(text_file.readlines()[0].split(', '))

## input series of strings
s = pd.Series(['00501', '00544', '00601', '00605'])
s_res = s.isin(zip_codes).tolist()

# [True, True, True, False]

## input series of integers
t = pd.Series([501, 544, 601, 605])
t_res = t.astype(str).str.zfill(5).isin(zip_codes).tolist()

# [True, True, True, False]
```